# How to load external script in react application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am here with a well-known problem related to external script loading inside react application. Despite many articles on the web and a lot of similar questions asked in StackOverflow, I can't solve my problem.

I am trying to integrate Yodlee Fastlink into my app. This is the script which I should run.

```
((window) => {
    document.getElementById('btn-fastlink').addEventListener(
        'click',
        (event) => {
            window.fastlink.open({
                fastLinkURL: 'fastlinkURL',
                accessToken: 'Bearer accessToken',
                params: {
                    configName: 'Aggregation',
                },
            }, 'container-fastlink');
        },
        false,
    );
})(window);
```

And here is the react component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const LinkBankDetails = React.memo((props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '/public/external-services/fastlink-integration.js';
        script.defer = true;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.body.appendChild(script);

    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="container-fastlink">
           <Button type="submit" id="btn-fastlink">Continue</Button>
        </div>
    );
});
```

And in the end, I get this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I have been struggling almost 2 hours and need your help.

Comment: What happens when you look at the script in the source panel of your dev tools? Is your local server responding with an HTML document? Also, your original script can easily be converted to a React button handler without adding this script every time `<LinkBankDetails>` mounts.

Comment: @evelynhathaway It just doesn't recognize it's a JS. <You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.>

Comment: If it says `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`, then you are serving your HTML file, and not your script as you expect. Look at the documentation on how to serve static files.

If that doesn't help, tell us your configuration details (Webpack, if you're using Create React App, etc.) and then we may have a shot at helping you

Comment: You saved my time ... thanks a lot. Changing src path to `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/external-services/fastlink-integration.js` solved the problem.You can write a response in order to make it accepted.

Comment: Yay! I am glad that fixed it for you! I added an answer so others finding it will see it's answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error is usually because your browser is trying to load HTML or non-compiled JSX as JavaScript.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

If you view or visit the source in your browser development tools and it says the following or otherwise looks like your `index.html`, you know that your local server is falling back to your single page application.

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

Look at the documentation for your project to see how to serve static files. If you are using Create React App, this [guide on using the public folder should help](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder).